# Omnistudio Datatable link to current record

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, omnistudio

I have a datatable in a flexcard where I show information from the Account object, example: Name, Account Number etc... the user wants to click on the account name in a row of the table and be redirected to the record... how do I put this link in a column in a datatable in omnistudio?

Comment: This should help: https://quip.com/ftaxAqKJknkj

Comment: Why is this a quip document? This kind of information belongs in the normal documentation where we can find it. Is there other content like this in quip you can point us to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the datatable supports adding links to it, but you can have an event listener for the custom event that datatable fires, `selectrow` and enable row selection on the datatable. Then you can have an event listener on the flex card that has datatable and action on it that takes the ID from the `action.result.id` and navigates to that SObject record.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually navigate to the record from data table using **rowclick** action in the event listener. You can use {action.result.Id} to navigate to the specific record after the user clicks on a row.